# Firebase Dynamic Links console error - "An error occurred when creating a new Dynamic Link" - when links just like it have succeeded in the past

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Having following error message whiles accessing firebase dynamic links from console.
"Firebase Dynamic Links console error - "An error occurred when creating a new Dynamic Link" - when links just like it have succeeded in the past"

Comment: Is this repeated error? Please open Firebase Support ticket if you can reproduce it.

Comment: Yes it was repeated, but was working on different projects. I just added its dependency to my android project, then worked :-)